# Component rendered 8 times

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand clearly why Row component rendered 8 times. Should I use custom comparing function in React Memo for this component? I'm using the [react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window) package. Please explain how it works for me. Thanks a lot.

Parent component of ListView: [CovidMap Component](https://github.com/quangkhaidam93/1653033-covid19-map/blob/master/src/components/covid-map/CovidMap.js)

My entire project: [Github](https://github.com/quangkhaidam93/1653033-covid19-map)

This is my code:

```
import React, { useRef, memo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FixedSizeList as FixedList, areEqual } from 'react-window';
import './ListView.scss';

const ListView = (props) => {
  const listRef = useRef();

  const Row = memo((props) => {
    console.log('Row rendering...');
    const { data, index, style } = props;
    const className =
      data.itemIndex === index
        ? 'PatienIndicator Highlight'
        : 'PatientIndicator';
    return (
      <button
        key={index}
        className={className}
        onClick={() => data.onClickPatient(data.patients[index])}
        style={style}
      >
        {data.patients[index].name}
      </button>
    );
  }, areEqual);

  const patientsLength = props.patients
    ? Object.keys(props.patients).length
    : 0;

  const data = Object.assign(
    {},
    { patients: props.patients },
    { onClickPatient: props.onClickPatient },
    { itemIndex: props.itemIndex }
  );

  console.log('List View rendering...');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.itemIndex) {
      listRef.current.scrollToItem(props.itemIndex, 'smarter');
    }
  });

  return (
    <FixedList
      className="List"
      height={300}
      itemCount={patientsLength}
      itemSize={50}
      width={'100%'}
      ref={listRef}
      itemData={data}
    >
      {Row}
    </FixedList>
  );
};

export default memo(ListView);
```

Comment: We'll need to see how ListView is being rendered (it's parent component and maybe the whole tree depending on where the issue is). Likely you are passing something down to ListView that changes references on every render.

Comment: There is no need for Row to be defined inside ListView, you should define it outside of the ListView function.

Comment: I have edited this thread with links to the parent component of ListView and the entire project. Would you mind check this? Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itemCount` prop tells FixedSizeList how many rows to render, so your list will render however many items are in your `props.patients` list, which is ultimately coming from the result of filtering the array returned by the fetch in the parent component. The `index` prop that you're using in the Row component is passed to the Row from FixedSizeList and refers to its position in the list, so it tells the first instance of the Row component that its index is 0, and Row uses that information to render the name of the first item in the `data.patients` prop. FixedSizeList passes its own `itemData` prop to each Row component as Row's `data` prop.

From the [react-window documentation for the FixedSizeList component](https://react-window.now.sh/#/api/FixedSizeList):

> itemCount: number
>
> Total number of items in the list. Note that only a few items will be rendered and displayed at a time.

and

> children: component
>
> React component responsible for rendering the individual item specified by an index prop

You're passing the Row component to FixedSizeList as a child, so it renders the Row component `itemCount` number of times.

React memo won't affect the number of instances of the component. All memo does is potentially improves performance of rendering each instance by reusing its last rendered version if the props haven't changed.

Comment: You mean it works like lazy loading? I just have tested by changing the height of FixedList and the numbers of rendering counts change correspondingly. And it will render every time I scroll in this list.

Comment: Not lazy loading since all of the data is loaded before the items are rendered. Just selective rendering since it only renders the list items that are visible (doesn't render the ones that are scrolled out of view) to keep the DOM clean.

Comment: I get it. Thank a lot!